# How to Get record from aerospike using list in java?

Tags: java, database, aerospike, aql

> My data at test.setName looks like this

```
| id    | cities              | lob        |
|-------|---------------------|------------|
| id123 | ["Cthdcn","Ctdel"]  | ["Lob132"] |
| id345 | ["Ctijs","Ctdelhi"] | ["LOB231"] |
| id765 | ["Cthui"]           | ["Lob875"] |
```

"cities" is already present as LIST INDEX, and want to get a
particular record by specifying cities array like(["Ctijs","Ctdelhi"])
via java client.

I want to retrieve (get) records by specifying cities array using
java. I am using the following method

```
    public Record testGet(String namespace, String set, String city, List<String> binNames) {
    Statement statement = new Statement();
    statement.setNamespace(namespace);
    statement.setSetName(set);
    Filter filter = Filter.contains("cities", IndexCollectionType.LIST, city);
    statement.setFilter(filter);
    RecordSet records = this.client.query((QueryPolicy)null, statement);
    return records.getRecord();
}
```

I am getting null. How can I retrieve that specific record? (AQL version 3.23.0)

Comment: In the above code, what did you pass for String city in testGet()?

Comment: @pgupta i passed "Cthui" as String city

Comment: select lob from test.setName in LIST where cities = "Cthui"  

this query is working fine in aql

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is small script in AQL in a text file, list.aql , to replicate your test:

## list.aql:

```
TRUNCATE test
DROP INDEX test.setName idx_city
SELECT * FROM test
CREATE LIST INDEX idx_city ON test.setName (cities) STRING

INSERT INTO test.setName (PK, id, cities, lob) VALUES ('key1', 'id123', LIST('["Cthdcn", "Ctdel"]'), LIST('["Lob132
"]'))
INSERT INTO test.setName (PK, id, cities, lob) VALUES ('key2', 'id345', LIST('["Ctijs", "Ctdelhi"]'), LIST('["LOB23
1"]'))
INSERT INTO test.setName (PK, id, cities, lob) VALUES ('key3', 'id765', LIST('["Cthui"]'), LIST('["Lob875"]'))

select * from test.setName

select * from test.setName in LIST where cities = 'Cthdcn'
```

Output in aql:

```
aql> run 'list.aql'
TRUNCATE test
OK

DROP INDEX test.setName idx_city
Error: (201)  Index does not exist on the system.

SELECT * FROM test
0 rows in set (0.156 secs)

OK

CREATE LIST INDEX idx_city ON test.setName (cities) STRING
OK, 1 index added.

INSERT INTO test.setName (PK, id, cities, lob) VALUES ('key1', 'id123', LIST('["Cthdcn", "Ctdel"]'), LIST('["Lob132"]'))
OK, 1 record affected.

INSERT INTO test.setName (PK, id, cities, lob) VALUES ('key2', 'id345', LIST('["Ctijs", "Ctdelhi"]'), LIST('["LOB231"]'))
OK, 1 record affected.

INSERT INTO test.setName (PK, id, cities, lob) VALUES ('key3', 'id765', LIST('["Cthui"]'), LIST('["Lob875"]'))
OK, 1 record affected.

select * from test.setName
+---------+------------------------------+--------------------+
| id      | cities                       | lob                |
+---------+------------------------------+--------------------+
| "id123" | LIST('["Cthdcn", "Ctdel"]')  | LIST('["Lob132"]') |
| "id765" | LIST('["Cthui"]')            | LIST('["Lob875"]') |
| "id345" | LIST('["Ctijs", "Ctdelhi"]') | LIST('["LOB231"]') |
+---------+------------------------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.124 secs)

OK

select * from test.setName in LIST where cities = 'Cthdcn'
+---------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
| id      | cities                      | lob                |
+---------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
| "id123" | LIST('["Cthdcn", "Ctdel"]') | LIST('["Lob132"]') |
+---------+-----------------------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.001 secs)

OK

aql>
```

In Java, you will have to iterate through the recordset to get each record that satisfies the query.

```
RecordSet records = client.query( .....)
while (records.next()){
  Record r = records.getRecord();
  ....
}
records.close()
```

I just tested the following code:

```
public void read () {
                Record record = null;
                Statement stmt = new Statement();
                stmt.setSetName("setName");
                stmt.setNamespace("test");
                stmt.setIndexName("idx_city");
                stmt.setFilter(Filter.contains("cities", IndexCollectionType.LIST, "Cthui"));

                RecordSet recordSet = this.client.query(queryPolicy, stmt);
            while (recordSet.next()) {
                record = recordSet.getRecord();
                System.out.println(record.toString());
            }

         }
```

and it worked for me.

```
$ java -jar ./target/dm-predicateFilter-1.0-full.jar
(gen:1),(exp:348432597),(bins:(id:id765),(cities:[Cthui]),(lob:[Lob875]))
```